# Google Chrome extension - integrate with Google Calendar

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

How can a Chrome extension alter the Google Calendar event editing UI?

I see that, for example, the Moxtra extension has managed to inject UI including a button just below the location. According to their [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1R4SASrK2I) they added a button to fill out the event description although when I installed Moxtra this no longer seems to work.

Stepping back from this a bit, it occurs to me that editing the Google Calendar page seems like something that could easily get messed up by future changes to Google Calendar. Perhaps it is better to edit the event description from the extension's own UI? If so, how can that be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done with content scripts and modification of the DOM.
They probably check Event edit page for specific selectors and try to insert their own elements in the page, if they found it.

So, if UI of Google Calendar will change, extensions like Moxtra will be probably also broken.

You are right about the edit of the description - it's safer. But you still need to get a description field and change a content of it. There is no 100% safe way to do it and don't break on the change of UI.